# when i am trying to extracting 400Mb tar file using java code it's getting( java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) )

Tags: java, android

When I am trying to extract a 400Mb tar file using java code it's getting `java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` and it is not extracting.

```
 private static void unTar(final File inputFile, final File outputDir){

       // LOG.info(String.format("Untaring %s to dir %s.", inputFile.getAbsolutePath(), outputDir.getAbsolutePath()));

        try {
            List<File> untaredFiles = new LinkedList<File>();
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputFile); 
            TarArchiveInputStream debInputStream = (TarArchiveInputStream) new ArchiveStreamFactory().createArchiveInputStream("tar", is);
            TarArchiveEntry entry = null; 
            while ((entry = (TarArchiveEntry)debInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) 
            {
                File outputFile = new File(outputDir, entry.getName());
                byte[] content = new byte[(int) entry.getSize()];
                if (entry.isDirectory()) 
                {
                    //LOG.info(String.format("Attempting to write output directory %s.", outputFile.getAbsolutePath()));
                    if (!outputFile.exists()) 
                    {
                        //LOG.info(String.format("Attempting to create output directory %s.", outputFile.getAbsolutePath()));
                        if (!outputFile.mkdirs()) 
                        {
                            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Couldn't create directory %s.", outputFile.getAbsolutePath()));
                        }
                    }
                } else 
                {
                   // LOG.info(String.format("Creating output file %s.", outputFile.getAbsolutePath()));
                    FileOutputStream outputFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile); 
                    IOUtils.copy(debInputStream, outputFileStream);
                   // IOUtils.write(content, outputFileStream);
                    outputFileStream.close();
                }
                untaredFiles.add(outputFile);
            }
            debInputStream.close(); 

            //return untaredFiles;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ArchiveException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have followed the code here **http://thinktibits.blogspot.in/2013/01/read-extract-tar-file-java-example.html**

Can any one help me?

Comment: When posting a question, please post THE FULL STACKTRACE so we can see where this error is happening.   Also, try uncommenting your log messages and show us what the program outputs.   This could be several things, and we'd need that info to help.

Comment: Is this Android, or Java EE? It matters.

Comment: android @DAve Newton

Comment: You should probably do your initial testing with a smaller file - that will help you figure out if you have program logic errors (or invalid assumptions), or if there is some sort of out of space / out of memory condition actually behind the problem.